# How must I format IP Address for SubjectAlternativeName in X509 certificate created by BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I use BouncyCastle to generate certificats. Now I want to add some `SubjectAlternativeName`, just like:

```
...
ArrayList namesList = new ArrayList();
namesList.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "*.test"));
namesList.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress, "127.0.0.1"));
namesList.add(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "zoltar@spkac.spectra.org"));
GeneralNames subjectAltNames = new GeneralNames(new DERSequence((GeneralName[])namesList.toArray(new GeneralName [] {})));
new_cert.addExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltNames);
...
```

Program executes without exception, but then I cannot see "IP Address". With `openssl` I see:

```
...
DNS:*.test, IP Address:<invalid>, email:zoltar@spkac.spectra.org
...
```

What is the correct form of IP address in call of `GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress, ...))`?

Comment: For me, **openssl** works (output is `DNS:*.test, IP Address:127.0.0.1, email:zoltar@spkac.spectra.org`). Running `openssl version` gives: **OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013** (in a Linux Red Hat 4.4.7-16 machine), maybe it's an issue on the version you're using

Comment: any other reason to believe it isn't correct? Try looking at it with some other tool, like a browser for example. The bouncycastle code is expecting a dotted ip quad just like in your example, and will throw an exception if it can't parse it.

Comment: It was not problem with `openssl`. I think it was problem with old `BouncyCastle` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was problem with very old BouncyCastle library. Application used version 1.39 from year 2008. So I upgraded BC to version 1.56 (December 2016) and rewrote application because BC changed some API. Now I see:

```
DNS:*.test, IP Address:127.0.0.1, email:zoltar@spkac.spectra.org
```

Comment: How did you rewrite the application? I have the same problem, could you give me some tips?thanks

Comment: I simply replaced BC jars with new version. Then using Eclipse I changed every line of code that was problematic. AFAIK lines that I cited in my question stayed the same.

Comment: I use tcpdump to catch the packet, and find the ip address is encode to something like this "[BE_ANY!?]"