# How could I encode ip address using bouncy castle library?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, snmp, asn.1

I am trying to realize snmpset using java, 
and I am using bouncy castle version 1.52 library to encode the values of oids, and now I want to encode an IP address, how could I reallize it?
I tried this:

```
new GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress,"xx.xx.xx.xx");
```

but get a

> snmpInASNParseErrs

error

UPDATE:

OK, I think i am very near to the right answer now, I used this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xx.xx.xx");
byte[] bytes = ip.getAddress();
v.add(new DERApplicationSpecific(0, new DEROctetString(bytes)));
```

now, the result is:

> C/x/IpAddress_04_04_0a_00_00_64

still need more help!

Comment: May be this is a duplicate question. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677981 ? The answer suggest to upgrade to BC v1.56.

Comment: updated to 1.56, still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem by this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipv4Address);
byte[] bytes = ip.getAddress();
v.add(new DERApplicationSpecific(0, bytes));
```